# Can I deploy AWS WAF (Web Application Firewall) without using the internet to protect my on premises infrastructure?

Tags: amazon-web-services, cloud, firewall

So my client wants to protect its on-premises infrastructure but it does not want to use internet from the user side.

So I was thinking whether I can use AWS WAF without the internet or do I have to use a third-party WAF for protection.

Please provide if any technical information on how can AWS WAF be deployed on-premises without using the internet.

I tried using AWS WAF with CLoudFront, however CloudFront also requires Internet to work, so now I am left helpless on how can I deploy AWS WAF without using the internet

Answer (score 0):

No, it is not possible to use Amazon CloudFront or Amazon WAF on premise. CloudFront is a content delivery network that proxies and caches content from endpoints located on the internet. To use CloudFront, you must have a web service that is open on the internet.

If you would like a WAF for an on premise application, you will have to search around for some providers/solutions that offer such services, though, most providers will require users to install an agent, which is a piece of software that collects statistics in realtime about your web service and reports it back to an internet endpoint so it can determine whether or not to block traffic.

May I ask what the WAF is needed for?

A WAF could be as simple as an HAProxy server with some set rules to prevent spam, abuse, etc. Fortinet, NGINX, OpenResty, Barracuda all provide similar services, but the primary use of a WAF is to prevent abuse from anonymous internet traffic rather than predictable on premise traffic.

Answer (score 0):

You can definitely use Amazon WAF to protect on-premise resources - I do this a lot, weekly at the moment.

You require an IP connection between Amazon AWS and your on-premise resources, such as VPN (I always use VPN).

Most typically I use an Application Load Balancer.  When you configure a target, specify the IP address on your on-premise resource.
https://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticloadbalancing/latest/application/load-balancer-target-groups.html#target-group-ip-address-type

The nice thing about using an Application Load Balancer is you can use free Amazon AWS certificates.
Once the Application Load Balancer is configured simply enable the WAF.